# Configure wifi connection on physical interface while using access point on virtual interface

Tags: wireless-access-point, remote-access, wifi-configuration, networkmanager

I need to remotely configure wifi connection. I thought to run access point, connect to this access point and configure connection with nmcli (NetworkManager).

I create ap using create_ap:

```
create_ap -n --daemon -g 192.168.55.1 wlp2s0 ap0
```

and list wifi networks using nmcli:

```
nmcli device wifi list
```

Here comes a problem. I try to connect with selected wifi:

```
nmcli device wifi connect SSID password PASS ifname wlp2s0
```

but I got error

> Error: Connection activation failed: (10) 802.1X supplicant failed

How can I resolve this issue? Or maybe there is a better way to do this?